# QPixmap Image doesnt appear

Tags: c++, qt

Im new with Qt and im making a game in it. I want to display icon but after putting there some code i cant find it anywhere. Im confused because i dont get any errors, so im pretty sure that i just didnt add something. Help.

Combat.h file

```
#ifndef COMBAT
#define COMBAT

#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class Combat: public QGraphicsPixmapItem{
public:
// constructors
//Combat(QPixmap *parent=NULL);
Combat(const QString x);

// setters/getters
void getOwner(QString x);

private:
QString owner;
};
```

Combat.cpp

```
#include "Combat.h"
#include <QGraphicsScene>


Combat::Combat(const QString x){
     // draw graphics
     setPixmap(QPixmap(x));
}

void Combat::getOwner(QString x){
     owner = x;
}

#endif // COMBAT
```

Interface.h

```
#ifndef INTERFACE
#define INTERFACE

#include <QList>
#include "Hex.h"
#include "Combat.h"

class Interface{
public:
    // constructors
    Interface();

    // getters/setters
    QList<Hex*> getHexes();

    void getOwner(int x);

    // public methods
    void placeHexes();
    void placeCombat();


private:
     void createHexColumn(int x, int y, int numOfRows);
     QList<Hex*> hexes;
     void createCombatIcon(int x, int y, QString z);
     int owner;
};

#endif // INTERFACE
```

Interface.cpp

```
#include "Interface.h"
#include "Game.h"

extern Game* game;


Interface::Interface(){

}

QList<Hex *> Interface::getHexes(){
    return hexes;
}

void Interface::placeHexes(){
     createHexColumn(100,100,6);
}

void Interface::placeCombat()
{
     createCombatIcon(100,100,":/grafika/atak_magiczny.png");
}

void Interface::createCombatIcon(int x, int y, QString z)
{
    Combat* icon = new Combat(z);
    icon->getOwner("player1");
    icon->setPos(x,y);
    game->scene->addItem(icon);
}
```

Im not sure where something is missing

Comment: How do you add the item to the scene?

Comment: call the parent constructor: `Combat::Combat(const QString x):QGraphicsPixmapItem(){`

Comment: @eyllanesc, the default constructor of the parent class is implicitly called. I am not sure your proposal will change anything.

Comment: Are you sure the `QPixmap` you create is valid?  You should check using [`QPixmap::isNull`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#isNull).

Comment: @eyllanesc Im using Qt Creator so it shouldnt be added automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding my graphics to resource file in Qt Creator...